# Encrypted resources in Visual C++/VB forms application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, encryption

I want to create a simple windows forms application with a PDF viewer control to display some PDFs which I will add as resources inside the project.
My problem is, I don't want users to use some tools to extract the PDF files from my application.

So the obvious solution is to encrypt the files and then add them as resources and decrypt them in memory at runtime. Encryption passphrase will not be stored inside code again for security reasons. So, what I will do is to ask the user to enter a predefined password when he/she opens my application which will serve as encryption passphrase. To validate the password, I will include an encrypted txt file with some text as a resource, decrypt it with password at runtime and check its contents to know if entered password is correct.
Am I going in right direction?

Though I know what I am supposed to do, I don't know how!
So, can someone help me with

1. Encrypting the resources beforehand with encryption passphrase which
   will be application password
2. Decrypting these files at runtime(in
   memory and not in temporary files) and passing them onto the viewer
   control.

PS: I am a newbie at encryption so kindly explain with little extra details..